# Problem with running 1 test class in Intellij from context menu

Tags: java, intellij-idea, maven-3

I'm running test class from context menu(1) and I'm getting mvn install(2) instead running only 1 test class, or even testcase. I want to run only 1 test.
What could be a problem ?

I'm using maven 3.8.4, IntelliJ 2021.3.2 Ultimate, and Java 11.

[image]

Comment: If you clilck the icon on the class level than all test cases within that class will be executed. The `install` is the name of the module... check your pom file ... Best would be to show your pom file...and the directory in your have your project..

Answer (score 0):

Check that you do not have the Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Maven | Runner | **Delegate IDE build/run actions to Maven** option enabled.

Also, check that you did not configure any [Maven triggers](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/work-with-maven-goals.html#trigger_goal) (e.g. before run/build).